# Give Xcode microphone permission while debugging

Tags: c++, xcode, audio, permissions, macos-catalina

I am trying to create a simple c/c++ console application for capturing audio from a microphone using portaudio. The Application compiles fine and is running without problems.

When I start the application from the terminal it captures audio just fine (Terminal asked for microphone permissions).

**Problem:**

When I try to debug my app in Xcode, it is not capturing any audio due not having permission to use my microphone. Xcode never asks for microphone permission. And I can not give Xcode microphone permission when going to the the Security & Privacy settings of my Mac.

**What I tried:**

I tried to reset the microphone permissions using

> tccutil reset Microphone

I tried to reset all permissions using

> rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC

I am on MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.1 and Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Edit:

`Audio Input` is checked in `Signing & Capabilities`.

Comment: Is `Audio Input` checked in  `Signing & Capabilities` for the target you are trying to build?

Comment: what's about to call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccessformediatype directly from the code ?